# Mule Dataweave - converting array of array into Array of object

Tags: dataweave

It would be helpful if someone could help me on below dataweave expression

[ {
"id": "1001",
"email": null,
"role": "admin",
"updatedAt": "2019-12-04T22:39:00.322000Z",
"Attributes": [
{
"id": "1001A",
"name": "GEO",
"value": null
},
{
"id": "1001B",
"name": "Group",
"value": "admin"
},
{
"id": "1001C",
"name": "Title",
"value": null
},
{
"id": "1001D",
"name": "Location",
"value": "New York"
}
],
"isActive": false
},
{
"id": "2001",
"email": null,
"role": "student",
"updatedAt": "2019-12-05T22:39:00.322000Z",
"Attributes": [
{
"id": "2001A",
"name": "GEO",
"value": null
},
{
"id": "2001B",
"name": "Group",
"value": "admin"
},
{
"id": "2001C",
"name": "Title",
"value": null
},
{
"id": "2001D",
"name": "Location",
"value": "New York"
}
],
"isActive": false
},
{
"id": "3001",
"email": null,
"role": "admin",
"updatedAt": "2019-12-04T22:39:00.322000Z",
"Attributes": [
{
"id": "3001A",
"name": "GEO",
"value": null
},
{
"id": "3001B",
"name": "Group",
"value": "admin"
},
{
"id": "3001C",
"name": "Title",
"value": null
},
{
"id": "3001D",
"name": "Location",
"value": "New York"
}
],
"isActive": false
}
]

And My Output should be like below

[
{
"id": "1001",
"email": null,
"role": "admin",
"updatedAt": "2019-12-04T22:39:00.322000Z",
"GEO" : null,
"Group":"admin",
"Title":null,
"Location":"New York",
"isActive": false

```
},
{
    "id": "2001",
    "email": null,            
    "role": "student",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-05T22:39:00.322000Z", 
    "GEO" : null,
    "Group":"student",
    "Title":null,
    "Location":"New York",
    "isActive": false
},
{
    "id": "3001",
    "email": null,            
    "role": "admin",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-04T22:39:00.322000Z",
    "GEO" : null,
    "Group":"admin",
    "Title":null,
    "Location":"New York",
    "isActive": false
}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun toObject(attributes) = ((attributes map ($.name): $.value) reduce ($ ++ $$))
---
payload map (($ - "Attributes") ++ toObject($.Attributes))
```

Using the provided payload as input, the output payload is:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1001",
    "email": null,
    "role": "admin",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-04T22:39:00.322000Z",
    "isActive": false,
    "Location": "New York",
    "Title": null,
    "Group": "admin",
    "GEO": null
  },
  {
    "id": "2001",
    "email": null,
    "role": "student",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-05T22:39:00.322000Z",
    "isActive": false,
    "Location": "New York",
    "Title": null,
    "Group": "admin",
    "GEO": null
  },
  {
    "id": "3001",
    "email": null,
    "role": "admin",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-04T22:39:00.322000Z",
    "isActive": false,
    "Location": "New York",
    "Title": null,
    "Group": "admin",
    "GEO": null
  }
]
```